# How to get RGB raster image with UTM coordinates

Tags: r, spatial, raster, utm, rastervis

I have a three layer raster with red, green, and blue channel values in it. I can plot the image with `raster::plotRGB`, but I need to add axes with UTM coordinates. Coordinates can be added with `axes=TRUE`, but they are floating in space and look bad. I would like to get the coordinates as they show up in plots created with the `raster` `plot` method, or better yet as they appear when using `rasterVis::levelplot`.

Ultimately, I need to create a raster image with UTM coordinates, a scale bar, and north arrow. This needs to be done using the `plotRGB` function in the `raster` package of R, or something with a similar functionality, as I need to assign the colour of each pixel by hand (no colour ramps).

Comment: Supply a small example, with reproducible data, showing what you've got so far and what you don't like about it?

Comment: Could you provide us with more detail about the origin of your data and the file format?

Comment: @klar, [this post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62740/raster-spplot-legend-how-to-add-a-title-beside-it) may be useful for you.

Comment: [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 4):

This is an ancient post, but it's a good question so I'll give it an answer.

I'll give an example of how this might be done with `rasterVis::levelplot`, using the 3-channel R logo raster data that comes with `raster`.

```
library(rasterVis)
b <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
```

#### Plotting three-channel RGB rasters with levelplot

Create an empty `raster` with the same dimensions and extent as the brick.

```
r <- raster(b)
```

Calculate the hexadecimal colours corresponding to the values of the RGB channels, and coerce to `factor`.

```
cols <- factor(rgb(b[], maxColorValue=255))
```

Assign these factor values to the raster's cells.

```
r[] <- cols
```

Plot with `levelplot`, extracting the hexadecimal colours from the levels of `cols` and passing them to `col.regions`.

```
levelplot(r, col.regions=as.character(levels(cols)), colorkey=FALSE)
```

[image]

#### Adding north arrow and scale bar

For the north arrow and the scale bar, we will look to @OscarPerpiñán's [docs](http://oscarperpinan.github.io/rastervis/FAQ.html#sec-5).

```
levelplot(r, col.regions=as.character(levels(cols)), colorkey=FALSE) +
  layer(SpatialPolygonsRescale(layout.north.arrow(), offset = c(5, 10), scale = 10)) +
  layer({
    xs <- seq(5, 25, by=5)
    grid.rect(x=xs, y=5,
              width=5, height=2,
              gp=gpar(fill=rep(c('transparent', 'black'), 2)),
              default.units='native')
    grid.text(x=xs-2.5, y=8, seq(0, 400, by=100),
              gp=gpar(cex=0.7),
              default.units='native')
  })
```

I'll leave it up to you to calculate the true distance (passed to `grid.text`) associated with the width, in map units, of the rectangles.

[image]